# VB.NET Trigger Datagridview Cell Click on Button CLick

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to trigger this command when the button is clicked

```
 Private Sub ClickDataGridview(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs)
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        TextBox1.Text = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString
        TextBox2.Text = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString

    End If
End Sub
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        ClickDataGridview()
    End Sub
```

but sadly I received two error

1. Argument not specified for parameter 'sender' of 'Private Sub ClickDataGridview(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs)'.
2. Argument not specified for parameter 'e' of 'Private Sub ClickDataGridview(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs)'

Should I make it an if statement to work? or should I try something else to trigger this event

Comment: When you call the `ClickDataGridview()` method in the `Button2_Click` event… where are the two parameters `sender` and `e`? The `ClickDataGridview(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs)` method is expecting these two arguments and the code is NOT passing them to the method, hence the two errors.

Comment: i try doing this ' ClickDataGridview(sender, e)' but I got this error
'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs'.'

Comment: When `Button2` is clicked and fires the `Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)` event, an `EventArgs` … `e`. … is passed to the event. This is not the same thing as the grids cell click event parameter `DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs`. This is why you are getting the error. Look at the signature of both posted methods… the `e` arguments are two different types.

Comment: You need to keep in mind that when the button is clicked, it knows “nothing” about the grid. It can get info about the grid like, which cell is selected or how many rows, but it will not know “which” cell was just clicked. If this is what you are looking for, then it would appear you need to subscribe to the grids `CellMouseClick` events and run the code you have in that event, with this approach the button would not be needed.

Comment: Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. That you're trying to get some code to work is not an explanation of the problem. In order to know what working code would look like, we need to know what you're actually trying to achieve. You haven't explained that though. Don't just describe the means and expect us to determine the end that those means don't achieve. You need to describe the actual end yourself. Basically, don't expect us to work out what you're trying to do from code that doesn't do it. Explain why you wrote this code in the first place.

Comment: Calling a method that handles an event is not "triggering" the event. The only way you can get a `DataGridView` to raise a `CellClick` event is to click a cell. If what you actually want is to execute the same code when a cell is clicked and when a `Button` is clicked then put that code in a method and call it from the other two event handlers. If that code requires information about a cell then you have to get that information in the two event handlers. Obviously the `CellClick` event handler provides that but, in the other case, you need to get it yourself from the grid. Research that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way but you have to careful about selection of cells . If you have to do only row operations then it is ok with this. I recommend don't do this instead that put button in gridview for each row and perform operation

```
 Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Try

 If DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0 Then

'Here you can change Datagridview row selection property and get selectedrows instead of selected cells
            Dim i_rowindex As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(0).RowIndex

            Dim i_colIndex As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(0).ColumnIndex


            DataGridView1_CellMouseClick(sender, New DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs(i_colIndex, i_rowindex, 0, 0, New MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 1, 0, 0, 0)))
End
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: thanks i have this command so no worries
   If SelectedRow = DGBRealTotal Then
            MessageBox.Show("You are Currently at the end of Row")
        Else
            SelectedRow = Val(SelectedRow) + 1
            lblCurrentSelectedData.Text = "The Selected Row is " & SelectedRow & " Row"

        End If

Comment: How do i accept an answer here? I'm kinda new to this site

Comment: Manufacturing an `EventArgs` and calling an event handler is bad practice. The common code should be in its own method and that method called from both event handlers. That common code only cares about the row so the `Click` event handler should be passing the `CurrentRow` while the `CellMouseClick` should be testing the mouse button and getting the row by index and passing that.

Comment: Obviously It is bad practice that's why I am not recommended to do this ..

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, however… I do not understand why you would want to force the user to “click” a button to set the text boxes. If you wire up the grids “SelectionChanged” event and update the text boxes in that event, then the user neither has to click on a button or a cell. If the user uses the Arrow keys, Enter key, Tab key or even “clicks” a cell, the text boxes will change automatically without the user having to click a button.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
  If (DataGridView1.CurrentRow IsNot Nothing) Then
    TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
    TextBox2.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString
  End If
End Sub
```

Or... better yet... if the grid uses a data source, then "Binding" the text boxes to that "same" data source is all that is needed. You will not have to wire up any grid events.

```
TextBox1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", datasource, "datasourceColumnName1"))
TextBox2.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", datasource, "datasourceColumnName2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

As I may have mentioned once or twice, don't call event handlers directly. Put the common code in it's own method and then call that method from each event handler as appropriate. In this case:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    GetRowValues(DataGridView1.CurrentRow)
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseClick
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        GetRowValues(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex))
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub GetRowValues(row As DataGridViewRow)
    TextBox1.Text = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
    TextBox2.Text = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you explain why not calling even handlers directly?

Comment: @8oris, the point of an event handler is to handle an event. They are still methods so they can be called directly but doing so makes your code less clear and anything that makes code less clear is bad. You have to pass fake arguments, which means that you can't use the parameters in the method. If you accept default event handler names then it is clear what those methods are for: to handle those events. If you want to call a method, that method should have a descriptive name and should only have reasonable parameters that you can pass and use if required.